# Aliens invading Earth who control adults and are afraid of wood

Tags: story-identification, aliens, soft-sci-fi, alien-invasion

Here's all I can remember :-

- It was a sci-fi story but had a horror-taste to it.
- It was about aliens from some other planet, who tried to invade Earth.
- The aliens could not (or probably would not) try and control children but instead tried to control adult minds.
- They tried to do so as they expected the children to obey the adults.
- At the end (?) some children take a young alien as hostage and somehow realize that the aliens are afraid of wood.
- When they realize that the aliens are afraid of wood, they are in a tunnel, trying to escape the aliens.
- It was in book form, but I cannot remember if it was a part of an anthology.
- This was in the childrens' section of the library and I read it about five years ago.
- At one point, they are in a treehouse and there are many adults queuing up in a neat line outside and the aliens use their powers over the adults to try and convince the children to come out.

Comment: Reminds me vaguely of _The Green Piper_ by Victor Kelleher, but I haven't read it for 30 years and now I can't find a plot summary, so I couldn't venture it as a real answer

Answer (score 4):

Look up the [*Visitors*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?21385) series by [Rodman Philbrick](https://rodmanphilbrick.com/) and Lynn Harnett! There are three books: [*Strange Invaders*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?668521), [*Things*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?668525), and [*Brain Stealers*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?27546). My husband told me about the books with this exact description and I scoured the internet.

The following excerpts are from *Brain Stealers* which can be borrowed (for free but registration required) from the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/brainstealers00phil).

> **The mob surged toward the tree house.** They didn't speak but we could hear teeth gnashing.

> **Very slowly and carefully we tiptoed along the tunnel, afraid even to talk.** Dirt sifted down around us and over us like mist. I don't know how long we moved like that, hardly daring to breathe. It seemed like forever. But finally the tunnel seemed to settle.

> Frasier pulled a baseball bat out of his pack, his favorite, an old wooden Louisville Slugger. "If any of those **slimy creepoid aliens** tries to grab us again I'm going to splat 'em like a bowl of Jell-O," he said, strapping his pack on confidently. But his voice cracked with fear.

> I thought I did but before I could say it, Frasier said, "**Wood! The aliens hate wood!** That's why the baseball bat worked."

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Since you found the series, can you provide any more info on the plot, particularly anything that ties into the OP's description?